# UITestControl not found in Firefox using Selenium components for CodedUI

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I'm running into issues while debugging my automated Coded UI tests.  The action is trying to click on a hyperlink on a web page.  On IE 8+ and Chrome 36, this works as expected.  However, on Firefox (downgraded to 26, even), it thinks the control is in a different location.  Here's my code:

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "firefox";
BrowserWindow myBrowser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(url));

HtmlHyperlink target = new HtmlHyperlink(myBrowser);
target.SearchProperties["title"] = myTitle;
Mouse.Click(target);
```

I've confirmed the properties using the Firefox developer tools (F12) and nothing changes between IE, Chrome, and Firefox.  When I `target.DrawHighlight();` on the control, it places the blue highlight box in a completely different location on the page than my control actually sits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Firefox 31.0.  Possible bug in the way the WebDriver interacts with 26.